# Picture List - How are they connected

Tags: word, wordplay, visual

Guess the word hidden with all the images.

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

[image: image 3]

[image: image 4]

[image: image 5]

[image: image 6]

[image: image 7]

Comment: Is the title also a clue?

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil not really.  It might help you get on the right track, but it's not a clue of what the answer is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here's what the pictures are:

- The nave of the Episcopalian church called Christ Church, in Detroit.
- A diorama, in the Los Angeles Natural History Museum, showing beavers building a dam.
- A model of a kind of ship called an anchor hoy.
- A performance by "The Goin' Band from Raiderland" at the start of a 2008 game of American football featuring the Texas Tech Red Raiders, at their home ground which is called the Jones AT&T Stadium.
- Generic clip-art of a boy (so far as I can tell).
- A skateboarder doing tricks on a floating skateboard ramp on Lake Tahoe.
- A messy teenager's bedroom; this picture seems to accompany multiple articles about messy teenagers and their bedrooms :-).

So:

> the word might be AGE, forming dam-age, Anchor-age, band-age, ramp-age and mess-age. I don't currently see any connection with the church or the boy, but enough of these fit that I bet this is right.

Thanks to suggestions in comments, here are some suggestions for the others:

> Man-age (perhaps it's not a boy, though it sure looks like one to me). Bever-age (ouch). Mass-age (but there's no service going on in the church and it probably isn't the sort that calls its Eucharists masses).

That seems reasonably conclusive.

Comment: Bever also supports beverage (bever+age)

Comment: The boy could also be a man to support your -age theory.

Comment: Ship --> VoyAge?

Comment: Oh, and bandage, of course. And maybe massage, but that's quite a stretch, because the church is empty.

Comment: @MOehm Massage or you mean Message?

Comment: I mean massage, @AlwaysConfused, because message is already covered by the mess in the teenager's room. Mass is a religious service of the Catholic Church, but there isn't any service going on in the picture and the church isn't Catholic.

Comment: Oh, I suppose he could be a man. Looks much more like a boy to me though. Beverage is probably right but ugh. I don't much like massage either for the reasons M Oehm gives. There are Anglican churches that use that term but somehow this doesn't look like one of them.

Comment: (@MOehm, I'm not sure of the relative timing of your suggestion of bandage and my putting it in my answer, but as it happens I hadn't read the former when I did the latter.)

Comment: My comment came after your last edit, so I hadn't seen bandage, but it was already there.

Comment: This is correct.  Man and Mass are the intended associations.

Comment: Bever/Man/Mass are all stretches :/ not a fan of that.